# paypal transaction value doesn't show

Tags: java, paypal

I'm following a tutorial from the paypal documentation to make it possible to pay through paypal. [Here](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal) is the code I'm trying to implement. However when I run the code it won't show me the amount that is supposed to be payed while it is set in the transaction through the code.
Does anyone know what needs to happen for this to work? Is the example either not complete or not up to date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. For the transaction to work something additional must be added to the paypal link.

When returned from paypal the link you have to navigate to to pay looks like this
`https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-3WC762911Y9384932`

however an additional parameter is needed for paypal to show the price that was set. To do so the following parameter needs to be added `&useraction=commit`

The entire link would look like this
`https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=commit&token=EC-3WC762911Y9384932`